# Why do I have to execute bash programs with ./?

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables, executable

Why is it that some bash programs will only run on my system when I type `./` before their name?

An example: In my `[...]/android/sdk` folders I have to execute `adb` like this:

```
./adb devices
```

Why not just `adb devices`?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html

Comment: This has just *got* to be a dupe.

Comment: What is missing from many answers is that this is a _relative path_ made out of a reference the current directory file (.) and the rest of the path from that point, in the context of [pathname resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you run

> echo $PATH

you will see a list of directories that your system will search for commands to run.

If you want to run commands in your current working directory, then you can run:

> PATH=$PATH:.;export PATH

You can add this line to your `~/.bash_profile` to have this behaviour persistent across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is the symbol for your current directory.  You have to include the `/` so it knows that it's not a `.` at the beginning of the file.  If you navigate to a different directory and type the directory of the file, you don't have to have the `./`